# The time it takes to reach 63.2% of the maximum temperature inside the a box.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, laplace-transform

this is for my undergraduate thesis. I think this is a combination of thermodynamics and calculus. This really troubled me for quite a while. So heres the problem.

Given:
 I have an incubator (box) with a volume of **1 m³**. The box is made of **plywood**.
 Initial temperature  = **84° F**.
 Power of the heat rod = **200 W.**

Question:
 **What time it takes to reach the air temperature at 63.2% of maximum temperature using the heat rod?**

Please comment if I missed out any given or important information to solve this.

Comment: Doesn't the type of matter that the box is filled with matter and the temperature of the heat rod?

Comment: *"I googled every pages of google"*. Not credible. Thermodynamically speaking. :)

Comment: Hint: $1-\exp(-1) = 63.2\%$. More seriously: you should pose this question on physics SE.

Comment: Thank your for your thoughts.

Comment: What does 64.2% of maximum temperature even mean? Are you aware that the initial temp 84°F is 63.2% of 443°F?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen 63.2% of maximum temperature. i mean the time constant of the box to have a maximum temperature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum temperature of the box will depend on the rate of heat loss through the box walls.  Otherwise the box will heat up indefinitely.  To know the rate of heat loss (assuming there are no leaks) you need to know the thermal conductivity of the plywood and the surface area of the box (assume a perfect cube).  There isn't one value for "plywood" as there are many different types and thicknesses.  So, this problem as stated, is incomplete.  Btw, the max temperature will be the point at which the heat loss is equal to 200W.

Comment: the box has an insulator inside. so pls assume that there is no heat loss.

Comment: oh i was corrected by someone that if theres no heat loss, the incubator will never reach its maximum temperature.

Answer (score 0):

In nature we do not have adiabatic walls. So you will have a loss through the walls of your incubator.

We know volume (1 $m^3$) but not total area. Besides, are all 6 faces with equal thermal resistance?

For thermal characteristics, you can see http://www.australply.com.au/technical/thermal-properties.

In your thesis, are you working with a thermostat to control/measure internal temperature?

I found these two sites with models that you can take as examples or modify according to your needs:

http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Systems/Thermal/SysThermalModel.html
https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/gs/define-system.html

The 63.2% refers to the time constant of your system. More at :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_constant

Comment: thank you. very helpful. I am working with a SHT15 temperature and humidity sensor to control the internal temperature.